# Project lost when pushing to github from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I have a Java project I was working on using Eclipse.

Eveything was fine until I decided to push it to a github repository.

I did all the steps and then an error message popped up saying `Problem occured when pushing to upstream` or something like that.

I went back to check out the project and it was not accessible from the Package Explorer anymore.

I went to the workspace folder and the project was gone and nothing in the trash bin either.

I also checked the github repo and it is still empty.

Is there anyway to get my project back ? It would really suck to do everything all over again.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-87b.htm

Comment: @JasonZ thanks bro, you are a life savior! maybe you should right it as an answer in case someone else gets a similar problem, and earn extra rep points in the process ;)

Comment: @MarioCervera The workspace was correct, I restarted it and everything, I even restarted the computer and the project folder was just gone. The solution was as suggested by @JasonZ, in the `Restore from Local History` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restore deleted resources from local history, according to eclipse official site:
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-87b.htm